# Get account / user information from AWS assumed role's access key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Given that someone have assumed a role

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html

```
{
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROA3XFRBF535PLBIFPI4:s3-access-example",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/xaccounts3access/s3-access-example"
    },
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "9drTJvcXLB89EXAMPLELB8923FB892xMFI",
        "SessionToken": "AQoXdzELDDY//////////wEaoAK1wvxJY12r2IrDFT2IvAzTCn3zHoZ7YNtpiQLF0MqZye/qwjzP2iEXAMPLEbw/m3hsj8VBTkPORGvr9jM5sgP+w9IZWZnU+LWhmg+a5fDi2oTGUYcdg9uexQ4mtCHIHfi4citgqZTgco40Yqr4lIlo4V2b2Dyauk0eYFNebHtYlFVgAUj+7Indz3LU0aTWk1WKIjHmmMCIoTkyYp/k7kUG7moeEYKSitwQIi6Gjn+nyzM+PtoA3685ixzv0R7i5rjQi0YE0lf1oeie3bDiNHncmzosRM6SFiPzSvp6h/32xQuZsjcypmwsPSDtTPYcs0+YN/8BRi2/IcrxSpnWEXAMPLEXSDFTAQAM6Dl9zR0tXoybnlrZIwMLlMi1Kcgo5OytwU=",
        "Expiration": "2016-03-15T00:05:07Z",
        "AccessKeyId": "ASIAJEXAMPLEXEG2JICEA"
    }
}
```

That entity then provide AccessKeyId in a presigned request to a resource I own - API gateway for example. I have access to all the params sent over and can use these params in aws cli calls

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/examplebucket/test.txt
?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
&X-Amz-Credential=<your-access-key-id>/20130721/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request
&X-Amz-Date=20130721T201207Z
&X-Amz-Expires=86400
&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host
&X-Amz-Signature=<signature-value>
```

Is there any information I can possibly get from these data like name of the assusmed role

Comment: No, you can't get role name from that.

Comment: Is there any information I should be able to get at all? @Marcin

Comment: Don't think there is anything you can get specific to IAM user/role making the request.

Comment: Assuming that you have access to CloudTrail for the role's account, you can search for the access key and find the event where the role was assumed.